# TypeScript does not infer callback return type in an object

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

TypeScript infers type correctly in this case, without me explicitly giving a type.

```
function myFunction<T>(callback: () => T) {
     return callback();
}

const result = myFunction(() => 5); //TypeScript knows that "result" type is a Number.
```

But it's not working inside an object, TypeScript forces me to explicitly give a type.

```
type MyObject<T> = {
    callback: ()=>T
}

const myObject: MyObject = { //Error happens, the compiler ask for a type here.
    callback: ()=>5
}
```

But compiler should know that "callback" is a function that return a Number. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There is no type inference for generic types the way there is for generic functions.  Currently the only way to "fix" it is either to manually specify `const myO: MyObject<number> = ...` or to write a helper generic function to get inference like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXz1Om).  Maybe if [ms/TS#26242](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) is ever implemented we could write `const myO: MyObject<infer> = ...` or even specify `infer` as a default, but for now it's not possible. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz The wrapper function is clearly working, I will accept your example as answer. However, in my real scenario, the code is much more complex and is very specific. This give me some idea to go on my own. Thank you.

Comment: here's a cool feeling: your fixed type declarations keep breaking, so you spend several days rewriting all your static variables to use a builder. everything works. then you check your linting and discover all the hints are gone because of this issue 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't currently have the concept of inferring type arguments in [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *types* the way it does when you call generic *functions*.  There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) which, if implemented, would allow the use of some sigil to tell the compiler to infer a particular type argument.  So maybe, some day in the future, you'd be able to write `const myObject: MyObject<infer> = ...` or `const myObject: MyObject<*> = ...` or even `const myObject: MyObject = ...` and get the behavior you're looking for.   But right now it's not part of the language.

The only way to get such behavior now is to use a generic helper identity function that returns its input:

```
const asMyObject = <T,>(m: MyObject<T>) => m;
```

So instead of `const myObject: MyObject = ...` you would write `const myObject = asMyObject(...)` and get the same effect:

```
const myObject = asMyObject({
    callback: () => 5
});

// const myObject: MyObject<number>
```

Here the compiler has inferred `T` to be `number` in the call to `asMyObject()`, and so the value returned from `asMyObject()` is of type `MyObject<number>`, and therefore so is the `myObject` variable.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsAPAFQHxQF4oBvAKCgqjQEMAbWxatAawC4oAKASkP21IC+pUmgD2AOwDOwKNUlwkqDISg4ANLg4BbdgpToseHgXxaA3CInSoWhPuVE5epcA5lKVOgyZtOx-ACsglwWAPShVFYytooGunYumOIArlqIEABOuEA)